# Is there a way to back up all files with AccuRev in a directory?

Tags: accurev

I'm new to AccuRev and not super familiar with it. I'm used to GitHub and a little confused about saving versions with AccuRev and how to use it.

In GitHub, I would work on some files in a directory and then use `add *` to add all the files to the staging area then do `commit -m <message>` to move them to the Head. Finally, I would use `push` to push all my changes and save them to my GitHub repository for others to see and for that version to save so I can go back one day.

I'm a little confused about this process with AccuRev. I have some directories that I have files in that I have modified. I want to save them onto AccuRev and have them backed up as a version.

I thought that I use the `keep` command to save them to AccuRev, but I can only do this with individual files and not with an entire directory. Or do I use something like `accurev keep -c <comment> -m` to keep all files in the directory and keep them recursively? Do I need to do anything else to push the changes?

Answer (score 2):

In the GUI, you will click on the "Outgoing" tab, in this view you will see all your modified files, select -> right click -> Keep or Promote (which will first keep).

If you are a CLI user, you can use "keep -m or -n" (see man page), this will keep all modified files in your workspace.  If you want to limit that to a certain directory, you can run a "stat -m" command and generate a list of files in that directory which you can use in the keep command (keep -l list.txt)

Once done, you will promote the changes.

Answer (score 0):

- Adding non-tracked new files: `accurev add` (which is technically the same as a keep). `add` has a recursive switch.
- commit in git: `accurev keep`
- push in git: `accurev promote`

Although the commit/push vs. keep/promote analogy doesn't hold entirely.